# Smart Tab : indenting with C-u <tab> does not work (beginning of a line)

Tags: indentation, tabs

(I haven't find any answer in previous topics)

I am using Smart Tab globally, i.e. I have put the following code in my .emacs :

```
(require 'smart-tab)
(global-smart-tab-mode 1)
```

I am writing a program in Fortran, and I often need to indent some lines, which, according to `smart-tab` documentation, is done either by prefixing the `smart-tab` command (i.e. `<tab>`) by `C-u` or by selecting the region to be indented before hitting `<tab>`.

After some research, I still don't understand why only the "selecting a region" method works for me : to indent just one line, I need to have it selected, but `C-u <tab>` does not work, and always gives to following message (which I don't understand) :

```
Symbol's function definition is void: cl-case
```

Being able to indent any line (and just one line) by using `<tab>` in a simple command would solve my problem (while keeping `smart-tab`).

Comment: Have you tried adding `(require 'cl)` to your config? That should help with this, but you shouldn't have any problem with this. Is your version of Emacs up to date?

Comment: Adding `(require 'cl)` to my config file soved the problem ! Thanks a lot DoMiNeLa10 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments on my question, adding `(require 'cl)` to my config file solved my problem (following **DoMiNeLa10**'s suggestion).

N.B.: I am using Emacs **24.3.1**.